# Did Angelina Jolie hire a hitman to kill herself?

Tags: celebrities

Apparently, Angelina Jolie was so depressed that she hired a hitman to kill herself.

The first instance of this story that I've come across was in [this article](https://www.heraldscotland.com/news/12227267.angelina-jolie-reveals-drama-of-how-she-tried-to-hire-a-hitman-to-kill-her/) from 2001, but it didn't cite any sources or provide any evidence that she'd actually done it. [SCMP reports](https://www.scmp.com/magazines/style/celebrity/article/3037864/10-remarkable-things-angelina-jolie-did-shiloh-was-born) that she said so in an interview in 2003, but again provides no link to the interview.

Did Jolie actually do such a thing?

Comment: Hope she got her money back.